# using Web3j how to Observable transactions of customerized ERC20 token

Tags: ethereum

Leverage Web3j TransactionObservable  together with filter, i can monitor ETH/ETC transactions as following code snippet illustrates

```
web3j.transactionObservable().filter(tx -> isWantedTransaction(tx)).subscribe(processTransaction,errorHandler,OnCompleteHandler);
```

But i  failed to find an efficient way to observe the transactions of customerized ERC20 tokens. Is there similar solution for customerized ERC20 tokens?

Comment: I would also like to know how this can be done. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: You need specified the contract address in the filter.